# How to use Except operator on non generic ICollection?

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have auto generated by the VS wrapper for WMI collection witch looks like this:

```
// Enumerator implementation for enumerating instances of the class.
    public class DiskDriveCollection : object, ICollection {

        private ManagementObjectCollection privColObj;

        public DiskDriveCollection(ManagementObjectCollection objCollection) {
            privColObj = objCollection;
        }

        public virtual int Count {
            get {
                return privColObj.Count;
            }
        }

        public virtual bool IsSynchronized {
            get {
                return privColObj.IsSynchronized;
            }
        }

        public virtual object SyncRoot {
            get {
                return this;
            }
        }

        public virtual void CopyTo(System.Array array, int index) {
            ...
        }

        public virtual System.Collections.IEnumerator GetEnumerator() {
            return new DiskDriveEnumerator(privColObj.GetEnumerator());
        }

        public class DiskDriveEnumerator : object, System.Collections.IEnumerator {

            private ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator privObjEnum;

            public DiskDriveEnumerator(ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator objEnum) {
                privObjEnum = objEnum;
            }

            public virtual object Current {
                get {
                    return new DiskDrive(((System.Management.ManagementObject)(privObjEnum.Current)));
                }
            }

            public virtual bool MoveNext() {
                return privObjEnum.MoveNext();
            }

            public virtual void Reset() {
                privObjEnum.Reset();
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I use except operator with this non generic ICollection?

Comment: with `OfType<T>` change `ICollection` to IEnumerable<T>; then use Linq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ICollection` inherits from `IEnumerable`, and there is an [`OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx) method which takes an `IEnumerable` and returns `IEnumerable<T>`, then you can easily use all LINQ methods when you got `IEnumerable<T>`, for example:

```
myCollection.OfType<object>()
.Except(myOtherCollection.OfType<object>(), new CustomEqualityComparer());
```

Since you have objects, you need to implement an [equality comparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx) for them an pass it to `Except` method, otherwise `Except` will compare your object by references.

Comment: Except doesn't use Equals it is using GetHashCode only